# How to change curve type in a-frame curve-component

Tags: aframe

I am using the [a-frame curve component](https://github.com/protyze/aframe-curve-component) to create paths for things to move along. I do not seem to be able to change the curve `type` though.

The documentation suggests that there are 4 available types (`'CatmullRom', 'Spline', 'CubicBezier', 'QuadraticBezier', 'Line'`) but I am unable to change it from the default `'CatmullRom'`.

Please see below the attempts I have made showing that trying to effect the type makes no difference. In one, I pass the type as an attribute of the `a-curve`, In another I pass the type as a property of the `curve` component (as this seemed to enable the `closed` property, and the final one where I do not change it all at all. (I have used the `a-draw-curve` to illustrate the rendered curves.

```
<!-- create the path with type defined as property of curve -->
        <a-curve id="track1" curve="closed:true;type:CubicBezier">
          <a-curve-point position="-3 0.5 -3"></a-curve-point>
          <a-curve-point position="-2 2 -3"></a-curve-point>
          <a-curve-point position="-1 0.5 -3"></a-curve-point>
        </a-curve> 
        <!-- Draw the Curve to visualise -->
        <a-draw-curve curveref="#track1" material="shader: line; color: blue;"></a-draw-curve>

        <!-- create the path with type defined as attribute of a-curve -->
        <a-curve id="track2" curve="closed:true" type="CubicBezier">
          <a-curve-point position="-1 0.5 -3"></a-curve-point>
          <a-curve-point position="0 2 -3"></a-curve-point>
          <a-curve-point position="1 0.5 -3"></a-curve-point>
        </a-curve> 
        <!-- Draw the Curve to visualise -->
        <a-draw-curve curveref="#track2" material="shader: line; color: blue;"></a-draw-curve>

        <!-- create the path with no type defined, result is the same -->
        <a-curve id="track3" curve="closed:true">
          <a-curve-point position="1 0.5 -3"></a-curve-point>
          <a-curve-point position="2 2 -3"></a-curve-point>
          <a-curve-point position="3 0.5 -3"></a-curve-point>
        </a-curve> 
        <!-- Draw the Curve to visualise -->
        <a-draw-curve curveref="#track3" material="shader: line; color: blue;"></a-draw-curve>
```

Which results in the following, as you can see they all appear the same.

[image]

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtc09zax/1/)

In each case if I look at the components attached to the `a-curve` I can see that it is falling back to `CatmullRom`

Am I doing something wrong?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other types are not implemented, i'm afraid. In the [distribution](https://github.com/protyze/aframe-curve-component/blob/master/dist/aframe-curve-component.js) (line 126), you can see a commented placeholder. I'd suggest filing an [issue](https://github.com/protyze/aframe-curve-component/issues).

---

Furthermore, 'adding' more curves to the component may not be as trivial as it seems, for only the [spline](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/curves/SplineCurve) and the CatmullRom curves can be created from an array of `Vector3` points, the rest of them takes a fixed set of three ( **start** - **mid** - **end**) or four (two middle) points.

Comment: @Nick, no problem, i'm afraid You'd have to create a new component just for other curves